# Usage of て form plus の (幸運が重なっての勝利)

Tags: grammar, て-form, particle-の

I saw this sentence in a book:

> すさまじい幸運が重なっての勝利だった。

It seems pretty clear that this means "I won thanks to incredible luck" but I was caught a little off guard by what appears to be the use of the て form + の particle.

Is that actually what this is, and what nuance does it represent?

Comment: 'て' and 'ての' has a difference subject.
In the case of "幸運が重なって", it is a modifier for a verb of "勝利する".
In the case of "幸運が重なっての", it is a modifier for a noun of "勝利".
(私は)すさまじい幸運が重なって勝利した。
(それは)すさまじい幸運が重なっての勝利だった。
It seems that the latter is a kind of written language, but I think they are same meanings.